# Differential operator definition by Wong.

Tags: operator-theory

[image]

Hello! I have just had a question with the definition of differential operator and various examples. With this definition given by Wong. Gradient and divergence are differential operators?

I ask this because, for example, the gradient is $\nabla=e_1\partial_{x}+e_2\partial_{y}+e_3\partial_{z}$ and to verify that $\nabla$ is a differential operator according to the definition, I need $a_{\alpha_i}(X)=e_i$ but I don't know if the value of $a_{\alpha_i}(x)$ can be a vector.

Similarly, would divergence be a differential operator with this definition?

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a matter of convention. If the above text is just an introduction to differential operators, then it's possible that the coefficients $a_{\alpha}(x)$ are assumed to be real-valued functions; that is, for a smooth function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $P(x,D) \circ f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. In this case, the divergence operator is an example of such an operator (of first order), being simply $\sum_i D^{i}$, with $a_i = 1$ for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$.

However, the gradient of $f$ is a function $\nabla f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, is a linear differential operator whose coefficients are vectors, and as you say, this corresponds to the coefficients $a_i = e_i$. This can be viewed as a more general definition of a differential operator. However, without further context, I cannot know whether or not this more general definition is being used by your text.

Comment: I understand. A more general definition would be to accept that the codomain of $a_{\alpha}$ can be vectors, right? In what book could you look for a definition of differential operators but in a more general way than wong? Thank you

Comment: A new question has just arisen. Really $a_{\alpha}(x)$ is a function (i.e $a_{\alpha}(x):\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R})$ or $a_{\alpha}(x)\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I'm not sure about books. The thing is, even if we allow the coefficients to be vector-valued, this the result is essentially a vector of scalar differential operators. So I think it suffices to discuss the scalar case primarily. $a_{\alpha}$ is a function $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, while $a_{\alpha}(x)$ is a real number, being $a_{\alpha}$ evaluated at $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I ask this, because I just read the following On $\mathbb{R}^n$, 0th-order PDOs with smooth coefficients are just multiplication by
some smooth function $f,$ which are the $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^n})$-linear maps
and it is not clear to me the linearity with which the operator is spoken

Comment: OK, in that case the coefficients are real-valued, and not vector-valued. The smooth function $f$ is the same as $a_0$, the 0th-order coefficient. so then for a 0th order operator, $Pu = a_0 D^0 u = a_0 u = fu$. The linearity here is that $P(mu + nu) = mPu + nPu$, where $m,n$ are $C^{\infty}$ functions. And this linearity can only hold if $P$ is 0th order, otherwise there will be some chain-rule-like terms that appear.